# Multiple file upload doesn't work (do I need javascript here?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html form:

```
    <form id="formulir" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="config-template-ecomerce.php">
    title-file<input  name="title" type="text" id="title"/><br>     
    color-one<input  name="color-one" type="text" id="color-one"/><br>

    <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px;" /><br>

    image<input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" onchange="PreviewImage();" multiple="true" /><br>
    submit<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

From the html form above, I want to select multiple file with one `browse` botton.

After I select one file with the browse botton, then the file of image will be changed if I select another file of image. What I want is the file is added not changed.

Do I need a script for this? I have tried this in three browsers: chrome, opera and mozila.

Comment: which browser do you use? and which version? Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/zL2tLmtL/

Comment: I have tried this in the newest version of opera (because I just download it) I also have tried this in chrome and mozila however I used the last-old versions of these two browsers.

Comment: see the fiddle and tell me what is the problem? : http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/zL2tLmtL/

Comment: Does it added the file? It only changed the file on my browser.

Comment: So what do you exactly want? Tell us in proper words(also in proper english!) please...Also, what do you mean by "file of image"?

Comment: I want to upload multiple files (As what I mentioned from the title of the question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59452/discussion-between-krupal-shah-and-al-kush).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our discussion in chat, you want to generate upload button dynamically. I can give you an example:

Suppose you have one upload button in html like this:

```
 <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="upload1" id="upload1"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then, you can add another upload button on `Click` event on previous button using `jquery`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#upload1').on('click',function(){
        var r= $('<input type="file" value="new button"/>');
        $("form").append(r);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/krupal/SP8de/34/)

Comment: @AlKush I have updated my fiddle right now..please check that.